# failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.io.IOException: getSecretKey failed: Password is not ASCII

Tags: android, gradle, android-keystore

This happens in Android Studio Beta. Used to work in the other builds as I recall. Now, I either have to generate a new key every time I generate the apk or manually enter my password due to this error. My password is ASCII. Simple characters A thru Z and a thru z. It takes the key just fine, but the next time I try to build this is what I get.

Digging back one error up in the output I see this:

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key0 from store "C:\AndroidRelated\KeyStoreForCompanyA\KeyStore.jks": keystore password was incorrect

I have it remember my password from build to build though.

Note that if I change this manually to what I know is correct, then it will build. Just a bug in Android Studio Beta maybe or is this overridden somewhere other than the Generate Signed Bundle or SDK dialog?

Comment: I started seeing this error when I upgraded to AS 4.2. As you already  said the only solution for now is to uncheck "remember my password" and enter it manually.

Comment: @kgmk Thanks bro, you saved my precious time. Google screws android IDE and Android  OS with every update. Uncheck "remember my password" , entered it manually and it worked somehow.

Comment: Issue is fixed. Check below link.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192538185

Answer (score 28):

**Solved**!

Step;

1. Clean your project
2. Generate signed yours bundle/.apk file
3. Uncheck the "Remember password"
4. Manually put your password at "Key store password" and "Key password"
5. Click Next and you Done!.

*Android studio update bring this bug.*

Comment: would like to add  , switch to Eng language, type with a single hand and probably finger ))

Answer (score 12):

It is a bug in Android Studio 4.2.+

You have to manually type password each time you generate signed APK!

Comment: any official reference for this or any bug opened against it?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191307563 @NoumanCh

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. Android Studio saves passwords in a bad format.

I solved it by typing the password manually again.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio tries to use the ASCII which is generated as you give your passwords but as it tries to re generate it based on your system language and datetime it can differ in some charachters. So, in some special cases it is better to use your keyboard to type your password.

[image: Generate Signed Bundle or APK]

As you see it makes different passwords in each part. It works correctly in some cases also but totally in act of preventing the trouble it is better to retype manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it quickly by **deleting the keystore file and create a new one** from the Build -> Generate signed bundle/APK -> APK -> create new options.

[image]